# VS Code Comments Panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, settings

I was looking at the
"comments.openPanel": "openOnSessionStartWithComments"
setting in VS Code, but I don't quite understand how this works. I can't find any info on Google or StackOverflow about this.

The comments panel, which is supposed to appear along side the Problems, Output, Debug Console and Terminal tabs doesn't show up.
[image]

How can you show the comments panel and what is it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments API is finalized in the May 2019 release

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35#_comments-api

Unless there is an extension that creates a `CommentController` the Comments panel will not show.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @rioV8. Any idea why they decided to keep just that one comments panel hidden by default?

Comment: @AndréCasal What is the use of a panel when there is nothing that interacts with it. It only confuses users that don't have a particular extension installed.

Comment: To me it's more confusing to have a setting for a part of the interface that doesn't show up. Not even when you set `"comments.openPanel": "openOnSessionStart"`.

Comment: As far as I could find out, there is no extension available enabling this comments panel, yet. Is this correct? I would really really love to use this feature :(

Comment: @jlang If you follow the link you will see there are at least 2 extensions that use the `Comments` API. One you need to compile and copy yourself.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for your answer, when I clone the extension at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/comment-sample - is there a way to use this extension without compiling and spawning it in a host window every time again? Sorry, I am not that experienced regarding the "authoring" perspective of vscode extensions :(

Comment: @jlang It is a typescript extension. You need to compile the extension to Javascript. So if it works in the spawn method just copy the whole directory to the VSC extension folder. In Windows this is `C:\Users\username\.vscode\extension`, for Linux/Mac search the location. Restart VSC.