# What is a comment thread in the vs code api?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

In the Api docs of VS Code there is a concept of Comment Thread under the workspace. Is there an example of this? What are these threads? Can developers have discussions on comments? Where are these comments saved?

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CommentThread

I tried googling and the closest I came to an example was this issue thread.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71171

How could I open this comment discussions in my workspace? Sorry if this is a newbie VS Code question - just recently converted.

Comment: You are looking at the VS Code API documentation, which is meant to be referenced if you were say developing an extension for VS Code.  Is that what you are doing? I don't think this "comment thread" thing is a "feature" so to say of VS Code.  Its something you can use as part of an extension you are developing.

Comment: I believe though that this might be used for say pull requests commenting.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591439/vs-code-comments-panel

Comment: @TimothyG. Yes, sorry I should have been more clear. I am looking to develop an extension which does commenting and I was not sure if this is some built in functionality by VSC to allow commenting already.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72356811/836330 these are for commenting on github pull requests and issues.

Comment: Thanks @Mark that confirms TimothyG. comments and answers my question. Thanks

Comment: if you want to add comments to source files stored in an external (database) file you can use the comment example extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I open this comment discussions in my workspace? Sorry if this is a newbie VS Code question - just recently converted.

This is an API used by extension developers. This is relevant to you if you want to create your own VS Code extension, and you need a way to display comments/discussions inside the code.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/comment-sample for an example + screencast. You first need to create a [CommentController](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CommentController). The CommentController allows you to create a [CommentThread](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CommentThread). A CommentThread is a list of comments. Each [Comment](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Comment) will have a body (text or markdown), author, date, etc.

A common use-case of this API is to show code review comments. In particular, this is used by the [GitHub Pull Requests](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github) extension, but you could imagine other use-cases for showing comments discussions inside a file.

> Where are these comments saved?

This API deals only with the UI. You decide where the discussions are stored (e.g. make request to a service, or store them on disk). Once you have the data inside your extension, use this API to render them.